# One Band, multiple connections?

Tags: microsoft-band

Is it possible (or to anyone's knowledge soon-to-be-possible) to connect a single Band to multiple devices? I'm trying to use the device in a scenario that calls for this capability (basically it needs to connect to the computer that a patient is currently standing in front of).

Short of this, is there any easier way to swap out connections than the current process of dropping/re-pairing the band from the device (and on a Windows Phone, at least, rebooting the phone)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Band will connect only to the last device with which it has been paired.  It cannot be "shared" amongst multiple devices.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I also found the request for this on UserVoice and added my 3 votes. Along with quasi-standalone apps ala WatchKit 2, which would solve this problem, as well. :)

Comment: @paul, can you share the link to that entry on UserVoice. I'd be happy to vote for it too.

Comment: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band/suggestions/8236575-allow-band-bluetooth-pairing-with-multiple-devices

Comment: Not 100% sure they're still monitoring that, though, since they've moved most everything to the Windows Feedback app.